# Inequality involving $\int_0^t e^{\alpha s^2} ds$. How to justify it?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, exponential-function

Let $\alpha>0$ and let
$$G(t) =\int_0^t e^{\alpha s^2} ds.$$
My Professor said that it is possible to estimate
$$ G(t)\le e^{\alpha t^2} +C,$$
where $C$ denotes a positive constant. Could someone please help me understand why?
I think it could be something related to the monoticity of exp functioin, but I am not sure about that.

Moreover, he left (as an exercise) to find a similar estimate but for
$$F(t) =\int_0^ t (e^{\alpha s^2}-1) ds.$$
Could someone please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$G(t) =\int_0^{\frac{1}{2\alpha}} e^{\alpha s^2} ds+\int_{\frac{1}{2\alpha}}^t e^{\alpha s^2} ds\leq \int_0^{\frac{1}{2\alpha}} e^{\alpha s^2} ds+\int_{\frac{1}{2\alpha}}^t 2\alpha s e^{\alpha s^2} ds=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2\alpha}} e^{\alpha s^2} ds+[e^{\alpha s^2}]_{\frac{1}{2\alpha}}^t.$$
Moreover $F(t)=G(t)-t$.

Comment: Robert Z, how justify the inequality $\int_{\frac{1}{2\alpha}}^t e^{\alpha s^2} ds\le \int_{\frac{1}{2\alpha}}^t 2\alpha s e^{\alpha s^2} ds$?

Comment: $2\alpha s\geq 1$ for $s\geq \frac{1}{2\alpha}$

Comment: Robert Z, thank you. So you can conclude that $G(t)\le e^{\alpha t^2} +C$, isn't it? And about $F(t)$, we can say that $F(t)\le e^{\alpha t^2} -t +C$?

Comment: Actually $F(t)\le e^{\alpha t^2} -t +C\leq e^{\alpha t^2} +C$ for $t\geq 0$.

Comment: Robert Z, thank you again. I posted a very close question some minutes ago https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4352384/prove-that-frac12-e-alpha-t2-1-ft-is-bounded-from-below if you want to come by and take a look.