# Prove that $\frac12 (e^{\alpha t^2}-1) -F(t)$ is bounded from below

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, exponential-function

Let $\alpha>0$ and $F(t) = \int_0^t (e^{\alpha s^2} -1)ds$. I am trying to prove that the quantity
$$\frac12 (e^{\alpha t^2}-1) -F(t)$$
is bounded from below.

I am reasoning in this way:
Since $F(t)\le e^{\alpha t^2}-t+C$, $C>0$ constant, thus it is
$$\frac12 (e^{\alpha t^2}-1) -F(t)\ge \frac12 e^{\alpha t^2}- \frac12 - e^{\alpha t^2} +t -C = -\frac12 e^{\alpha t^2} +t -C-\frac12$$
which it is not bounded from below.

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $g(t):= \frac{1}{2}(e^{\alpha t^2}-1)-F(t)$ $(t \in \mathbb{R})$. Then
$g'(t) = (\alpha t -1)e^{\alpha t^2} +1$. Thus $g'(t) \to \pm \infty$ $(t \to \pm \infty)$. Hence $g(t) \to \infty$ $(t \to \pm \infty)$. Since $g$ is continuous $\min g(\mathbb{R})$ exists.

Edit: There are $a < 0$ and $b > 0$ such that $g'(t) \le -1$ $(t \le a)$ and $g'(t) \ge 1$ $(t \ge b)$. So, by the Mean Value Theorem $g(t) -g(b) \ge t-b$ $(t \ge b)$. Thus $g(t) \to \infty$ $(t \to \infty)$. The limit  $g(t) \to \infty$ $(t \to -\infty)$ can be proved the same way. Next, $g(0)=0$. Since  $g(t) \to \infty$ $(t \to \pm \infty)$ there is a compact interval $[-c,c]$ such that $g(t)>0$ for $|t|>c$. Hence $\min g(\mathbb{R}) = \min g([-c,c])$.

Comment: Gerd, thank you for the answer. Why $g^{\prime}(t)\to \pm\infty\implies g(t)\to \infty$? And why it ensure that the minimum exists?

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: Gerd, so it si true that that quantity is bounded from below?

Comment: Yes, sure. For all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $g(t) \ge \min g(\mathbb{R})$, and it is clear that $\min g(\mathbb{R}) \le 0$. Moreover, for $\alpha$ sufficiently big it seems that $\min g(\mathbb{R}) =0$, since then $g'(t)=0$ if and only if $t=0$.